# PayPal - (login) Invalid return invalid client_id or redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, paypal, oauth, paypal-sandbox

I've tried almost everything, I can't count the number of times I've checked everything to make sure all the information is correct.

Again and again "Invalid return invalid client_id or redirect_uri".

Please, if someone has already had this problem, tell me how to solve it. I have the impression that the problem is on paypal's side, not mine.

```
  login.render ({
    "appid":"<My client id>",
    "authend":"sandbox",
    "scopes":"openid profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
    "containerid":"lippButton",
    "responseType":"code",
    "locale":"en-us",
    "buttonType":"LWP",
    "buttonShape":"pill",
    "buttonSize":"lg",
    "fullPage":"true",
    "returnurl":"https://easyclaimstore-dev.myshopify.com/admin/apps/64af2004495b12c144df08b8ebfc2a90/login"
  });
```

[image: second img]

Comment: The reidrect uri must exactly match one that you have configured over in their developer settings.  Exactly match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot does not show the Return URL. It's at the top of the App settings and must match.

If that doesn't resolve it your question should include the sandbox client ID.